# What is "cooked value" returning in Powershell's get-counters cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I'm using Powershell to return values for certain performance counters, and I'm seeing that it is referring to "Cookedvalues" when presenting the information. I'm looking for each counter hit to be reported on it's own, so I can do analysis like seeing the 90th percentile values or max/min, so I need to know how it is arriving at Cooked Value. Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
$computer         = $ENV:Computername 
$instance         = "_total" 

@("\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Current Disk Queue Length", 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\% Disk Time", 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Queue Length", 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length", 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length", 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer" 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read", 
  "\\$Computer\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Write") |% { 
    (Get-Counter $_.replace("*",$instance)).CounterSamples } | 
    Select-Object Path,CookedValue | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize 


#   Retrieve the current Processor performance counter information. 
$computer         = $ENV:Computername 
$instance         = "_total" 
@("\\$Computer\Processor(*)\% Processor Time", 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\% User Time", 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\% Privileged Time", 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\Interrupts/sec", 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\% DPC Time", 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\DPCs Queued/sec" 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\% Idle Time", 
  "\\$Computer\Processor(*)\% Interrupt Time") |% { 
    (Get-Counter $_.replace("*",$instance)).CounterSamples } | 
    Select-Object Path,CookedValue | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize 

# Retreive the current Memory counter information 
$computer         = $ENV:Computername 
$instance         = "_total" 
@("\\$Computer\Memory\Page Faults/sec", 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Available Bytes", 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Committed Bytes", 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Commit Limit", 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Pages/sec", 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Free System Page Table Entries" 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Pool Paged Resident Bytes", 
  "\\$Computer\Memory\Available MBytes") |% { 
    (Get-Counter $_.replace("*",$instance)).CounterSamples } | 
    Select-Object Path,CookedValue | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://blogs.technet.com/b/nexthop/archive/2011/06/02/gpsperfcounters.aspx, a "CookedValue" is:

> performance counters typically have raw values, second values, and cooked values. The raw values and second values are the raw ingredients used by the performance counter, and the "cooked value" is the result of "cooking" those ingredients into something for human consumption.

So apparently the CookedValue is the result of combining the counter's raw data to get a usable value that you can understand and work with.

Comment: That makes sense. Looking at the values again on a non-stressed system, they do seem to make sense in the context of the counter they're representing. I still wish I knew what math they're doing to arrive at the value, but that gets me what I need for now. Thanks!